# Convertir una cadena de string a Json

Tags: python, json

Hola a todos necesito convertir una lista de cadenas separadas por puntos a json, necesito un algoritmo para hacer esta tarea:
Entrada:

```
 l = []
  l.append("a.a")
  l.append("a.b")
  l.append("a.c")
  l.append("a.d")
  l.append("a.e.d")
  l.append("a.e.e")
  l.append("b.a")
  l.append("b.b")

Salida:
     {a:{a,b,c,d,e:{d,e}},b:{a,b}}
```

Comment: Hola Yadiel, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so], te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Comment: Creo que esto es lo que  busca [json.loads()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) ejemplo: `suVariable = json.loads(cadena)`